How can I solve the Enter key not working in Delphi11?
I need help please,
I was programming in Delphi 11 normally, suddenly when I write a code or want to modify a code in unit and press the enter key on keyboard, the writing does not go down, only the cursor goes down.
I tried to close Delphi and then restart it, but the same problem still exists. I also turned off the computer and the same thing happened. Even if I opened a new project, the same problem remains.

"I also turned off the computer and the same thing happened." - I misread this as restarting Windows, because then the mode of the Ins key would not have survived. But just hibernating Windows changes nothing, of course.

@AndreasRejbrand No, by far! I'm old enough to use Shift+Del and Shift+Ins to cut and paste, so I know the insert/overwrite mode by Ins for decades/since DOS. My comment states that "turned off the computer" cannot have meant to shut it down, because only in the former the program in question could still remain open (and still be in insert mode). I never implied system wide functionality - you misinterpreted that.

You have probably inadvertently changed from Insert to Overwrite mode in the Delphi editor. There is a selection menu for it near the bottom left corner of the editor:

The Ins key also toggles between modes.

It is also worth pointing out that the INS key toggles between insert and overwrite mode. (This is a very useful feature that I use daily. It has been a standard part of text editors since at least the 90s.)

Thank you very much, I didn't know about this, I probably clicked on it by accident when I wanted to delete something and the status changed, thank you too, I really appreciate your help, I wish you a productive day sir @AndreasRejbrand < =) >

Wait Delphi stores the Insert/Override text editing mode when closing. No other Editor does this. They always use Insert as default mode when started.
